# How to access the elements in numpy array of sets?

Tags: python, numpy, set

By mistake I used numpy array over a set to save my result. The run was time-consuming and it is hard to repeat it. It seems something is stored in the variable, but how can I retrieve the elements inside it?

To simplify, I did something like

```
#import numpy as np
result = np.array({1,2,3,4})
```

Now how can I access the elements (i.e., 1,2,3,4) in result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only "problem" here is that your array is a scalar (otherwise you could use `result[0]`). In this case you can simply use `result.item()`.

Comment: Cool. It works. Thanks.